# Rails 4 permit any keys in the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I pass a params like this

```
{
  "utf8" => true,
  "supply" => {
    "items" => { 111 => 112, 89 => 10},
    "another_params" => "something"
  }
}
```

My `supply_params` are:

```
params.fetch(:supply, {}).permit(:another_params, items: {})
```

But I get an `unpermitted parameters 111 and 89`. How can I make `items` permit all kinds of keys?

Comment: just allowing the parent key should allow all child keys.  so simply allowing `supply` will be enough here.

Comment: Wouldn't simply `params.fetch(:supply, {}).permit(:another_params, :items)` work in your case?

Comment: Pawel, It seems no....

Comment: @asiniy - did you see [this thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454)?  Seems like it may address your use case.

Comment: You are not using nested-attributes or `fields_for` ? This will aid in building a more railsy params-array (and allow more stringent permissions).

Comment: @nathanvda, not my case. These attributes goes to form object

Comment: @steveklein you should it as an answer, so the OP can give you credit :)

Comment: @asiny i think you mean the attributes come _from_ the form object, and I am saying: maybe you should write your form differently so it posts in a way rails can automatically parse more correctly. But if you are happy with your solution, it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454) in github provides a solution:

```
def supply_params
  params.require(:supply).permit(:another_params).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:items] = params[:supply][:items] if params[:supply][:items]
  end
end
```

The idea is to explicitly permit any known attributes which are needed and then tack on nested attributes.

Comment: Lol I had forgotten all about this and then saw the comments today from you and @nathandva so I wrote it up.  As long as you've solved your problem, that is fine.  In the future, I'll try to write something up earlier so you can accept it.

Comment: And I forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the @steve klein [link to github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454), this is considered as a good solution:

```
params.permit(:test).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:more] = params[:more]
end
```

Comment: Why not give Steve Klein the real credit, and let him answer?

Comment: I can do that, but I don't know how to do it.