# Rails permit nested hash parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, parameter-passing, strong-parameters

Here are my params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"g0mNoBytyd0m4oBGjeG3274gkE5kyE3aPbsgtqz3Nk4=", "commit"=>"Save changes", "plan_date"=>{"24"=>{"recipe_id"=>"12"}, "25"=>{"recipe_id"=>"3"}, "26"=>{"recipe_id"=>"9"}}}
```

How do I permit:

```
"plan_date"=>{"24"=>{"recipe_id"=>"12"}, "25"=>{"recipe_id"=>"3"}, "26"=>{"recipe_id"=>"9"}}
```

To get an output that looks like:

```
permitted_params = ["24"=>{"recipe_id"=>"12"}, "25"=>{"recipe_id"=>"3"}, "26"=>{"recipe_id"=>"9"}]
```

So that I can use the following to save:

```
permitted_params.each do |id, attributes|
  Object.find_by_id(id.to_i)
  Object.update_attributes(attributes)
end
```

I'm trying the following, but it's not working:

```
def permitted_params
  params.require(:plan_date).permit(:id => [:recipe_id])
end
```

My version in fact, isn't letting anything go through =(

Comment: I answered a similar question - hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894070/rails-4-permit-any-keys-in-the-hash/31033036#31033036.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hashes with integer keys are treated differently and you can declare
>   the attributes as if they were direct children
>
> [RailsGuides - Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

```
def permitted_params
  params.require(:plan_date).permit([:recipe_id])
end
```

Although the "Rails Way" is to use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

```
<%= form_for :plan_date do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :recipes do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :foo %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This gives you a nested attributes hash:

```
plan_date: {
  recipes_attributes: [
    "0" => { foo: 'bar' } 
  ]
}
```

Which can be used with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to create and update nested models.

```
def update
  @plan_date.update(permitted_params)
end

def permitted_params
  params.permit(:plan_date).permit(recipies_attributes: [:foo])
end
```